# Unable to update, $push in mongoose, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add comment option in my blog, but i am getting while updating it in schema using update(), $push. What i am doing wrong?

***posts.js-> routes***

```
var posts = require('../models/posts');
   router.post('/addcomment', function(req, res, next) {
        // Get form values
        var name        = req.body.name;
        var body        = req.body.body;
        var postid      = req.body.postid;
        var commentdate = new Date();
        console.log('postid:'+postid+'Comment:'+body);
        // Form validation
        req.checkBody('body', 'Body field is required').notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if (errors) {
            var posts = db.collection('posts');
            posts.findById(postid, function(err, post) {
                res.render('show', {
                    "errors": errors,
                    "post": post
                });
            });}
        else {
            var comment = {
                "name": name,
                "body": body,
                "commentdate": commentdate
            };
            console.log(comment.name);
            var posts = db.collection('posts');
            posts.update({
                    "_id": postid
                },
                {
                    "$push":{
                        "comments": comment
                    }
                },
                {
                    save: true,
                    new: true
                },
                function(err, doc) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);               
                    } else {
                        req.flash('success', 'Comment added');
                        res.location('/posts/show/' + postid);
                        res.redirect('/posts/show/' + postid);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

***posts.js-> models***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var lists = new Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author_username:{
        type: String
    },
    author_name: {
        type: String
    },
    category:{
        type: String
    },
    body:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    // comments: [CommentsSchema]
    comments: [{
        name:{
            type: String,
        },

        body:{
            type: String,
        },
        parent: {
            type: String
        },
        commentdate :{
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var posts = module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', lists);
```

**index.jade**

```
if post.comments
                                h3 Comments
                                each comment, i in post.comments
                                    p.comment-name #{comment.name}
                                    p.comment-text #{comment.body}
```

***OUTPUT***

> postid:57fgc24d24d5f3hj, Comment: 'this is a comment'.

I have tried following questions asked here earlier but couldn't make out.
And how can add function to add comment on comment.
Thanks

Comment: The `{ new: true, save: true }` options are actually not valid for the `.update()` method. It looks like you misinterpreted someones "old
 blog post where they were actually using `.findOneAndUpdate()` or similar. Not that this is that relevant to any problem here. I would generally suspect that `var errors = req.validationErrors();` is not returning what you think it does. So in fact you are probably just always branching to the code that simply does the `findById()`. But again the `db.collection()` call is not valid or required for `mongoose` and you appear to be "overwriting" the model.

Comment: I added `{ new: true, save: true }` after reading an answer here only, even before adding i was not able to update. I am following a tutorial (yes, its 2yrs old) there they used `db.get()` , `.update()` , ` $push().` and they not even used schemas. After following docs, blog and some questions here i added schemas and db.collection(). While adding post in my blog I did the same thing but with `.insert()` and it is working, so i dont think `var errors` are any issue. Though i removed this part but still the problem is same.

Comment: Right now I removed db.collecction() and it worked.But could you explain me why I have to add db.colllection while inserting and not when updating? Thanks.